How can I troubleshoot and fix an SSH “connection corrupted” issue on a work managed Mac after upgrade to macOS Sequoia?
On Monday my work laptop got updated to macOS 15.0.1 Sequoia and my previously stable SSH connection is now very unstable.
I don't have a problem establishing a connection; I get kicked off at random times in the middle of actual work with this error message:
Bad packet length 1984141761.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to x.y.z.7 port 22: Connection corrupted

tink@m1:~ $ echo 1984141761/1024/1024| bc
1892

Research on Reddit suggested adding the SSH executable to the firewall setup, but this isn’t a fix (makes no difference) for me.
A comment here suggested test whether adding the option -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com helps. When I do that, a different error message arrives:
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to x.y.z.7 port 22: message authentication code incorrect

There were no changes to the network or my setup other than upgrading from Sonoma to 15.01. Corporate software includes Intune MDM management, Microsoft Defender for Mac and the Huntress Agent security software.
Does anyone have a fix or troubleshooting advice for SSH instability on macOS Sequoia 15.0.1?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You may have an issue if you are using any 3rd party network extensions like LuLu / Little Snitch / VPNs / MDM. Very likely if your machine is provided by your employer.
macOS Sequoia has apparently introduced a bug in 15.0 where the macOS Firewall doesn't play well with other networking products. It's supposedly been acknowledged by Apple and fixed in the 15.1 Beta, build is 24B5070a as of 2024-10-08. 15.1 is reportedly being released at the end of October.
macOS 15.0.1 went some way towards a fix, but still felt unreliable.
I have just updated to macOS 15.1 Beta 3 (24B5070a) and found that SMB copies and rsync (over ssh) seems to feel more solid. And without wishing to drag up a very old meme, Safari does have a certain 'snappiness' about it, but everything is relative.
The 15.1 update brings some other changes. There is a new Filters section in Settings | Network. Of course in typical Apple fashion there are now 3 places in Settings where an extension's behaviour can now be controlled. eg. I see references to LuLu in:

Settings | Network | Filter (the filter behaviour)
Settings | General | Login Items & Extensions (the Login behaviour)
Settings | General | Login Items & Extensions | Network Extensions (the extension behaviour)

However, 15.1 doesn't yet seem to bring a fix to the macOS Firewall (first seen in 15.0), where deletion of old rules appears to still be disabled via the GUI.
Context
I have copied the larger part of this answer from a previous answer I gave, on a possibly unrelated question. As such I repeat a lot of the same references @bmike has given in his answer.

https://techcrunch.com/2024/09/19/apples-new-macos-sequoia-update-is-breaking-some-cybersecurity-tools/

Personally I had a problem with dropped ssh connections to my local RPi4 NAS - usually with some sort of encryption error, and dropped file copies over SMB from the same device.
I wondered about a bad interaction with LuLu, and ended up uninstalling LuLu (seems a disable isn't enough) until Apple fix the issue.

https://github.com/objective-see/LuLu/issues/639

The choice appears to be, disable either of the 3rd party extensions, or the macOS FW.
SSH issues:

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-sequoia-builtin-firewall-does-not-allow-ssh-login.2436706/

DNS issues:

https://mjtsai.com/blog/2024/09/18/macos-firewall-regressions-in-sequoia/

Another issue the macOS firewall has is that existing rules can't be edited. the - button in the dialog is inactive. Presumably it can be done  in Terminal but I've not experimented.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255759412?sortBy=rank


Thank you for the great detail, Andy ... now I wonder whether I should grin and bare it and live w/ wonky SSH till 15.1 drops or try to argue w/ the service provider to get me onto a beta. I've ansibled my .profile on all target hosts to automatically open a screen session, so damage is kept to a minimum, losing a couple of characters left in the keyboard buffer, followed by some swearing and being back on a 1 to 2 seconds later ...

It’s a real pain @tink especially since the instability is triggered by the presence of the network extension, not caring if it’s enabled or disabled. TGIS&T - thanks for tmux and screen

Even though it’s not practical you may wish to get on a macOS beta 15.1. If not, try disabling completely your network filtering software to troubleshoot an incompatibility between the new OS and security software might be needed here. Ensure you review and make all firewall and networking elections needed in case they were reverted at install time. This means a new MDM push for corporate managed Macs.
One consumer oriented piece of software that reported instability in the network extension framework late in the macOS 15 beta testing cycle was LuLu.

https://objective-see.org/products/lulu.html

Other VPN and firewall providers may be struggling with changes Apple potentially introduced late in the release test window. Check with your IT department if you can’t test without their standard software installed or load a clean OS. It’s almost been a month so they certainly should have a full bulletin on what to test now and what’s broken.

https://techcrunch.com/2024/10/07/apple-fixes-bugs-in-macos-sequoia-that-broke-some-cybersecurity-tools/


Thank you for your effort and support, I don't think I'll  be able to get them to turn off the firewall. I did ask them to stop the rollout of Sequoia to technical staff ...

Did you fixe this by reinstalling the same version of the OS as you had when the problem occurred @tink or have third party updates made this go away?

sorry, completely missed that follow-up (didn't get pinged for the question). I'm not sure what you mean by "made that go away". I still have the ssh issue (and discovered a new one, using vmWare HTML5 console I keep getting disconnected from consoles as well now).

I applied 15.1 yesterday morning and haven't seen any ssh drops or disconnects from vSphere virtual consoles since; that is not to say that it is fixed for everyone, there are enough people out there who still see issues after the .01 => .1 update.
Firewall Issues - ssh_dispatch_run_fatal errors during SSH

I've been suffering from this problem for weeks, and it was solved in the last two days. However I'm sure which of the following worked. The steps I tried were:

in System Settings - Firewall, manually add ssh (the binary file) and iTerm2.app
completely uninstall Little Snitch and reinstall it
manually allow ssh and iTerm2 in Little Snitch
upgrade from macOS 15.0.1 to 15.1

(maybe reboot the computer after each operation)
If you have still have this problem, maybe give a try
